# Spring loading application.properties based on tomcat servlet context definition

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration-files

I need to have a development and production settings for our spring project. I understand that you can use profiles for spring but that is not something that we can do.

What I want to do is place on the development environment a test-application.properties file and on production a prod-application.properties file. In the  tomcat context definition we sent the following:

```
<Context>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>properties_location</param-name>
        <param-value>file:C:\Users\Bill\test-application.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
</Context>
```

And we can have the value changed for the production servers. In the spring config we have something like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>${properties_location}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
</bean>
```

But we keep getting errors like:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could
>   not load properties; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
>   [/${properties_location}]

Any ideas on how to solve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One feature of  PropertyPlaceholder is that you can define multiple resource locations.
So for example you can define **your-production-config.properties** along with **file:C:/Users/${user.name}/test-application.properties**

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:your-production-config.properties</value>
            <value>file:C:/Users/${user.name}/test-application.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>        
</bean>
```

for production you need to place prod configuration into classpath somewhere(really not important where exactly, just classpath) - for local env you can use convension like this file:C:/Users/${user.name}/test-application.properties

Comment: I did the same thing but forgot the ignoreResourceNotFound. Now works. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Also, because you indicate SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE, any properties specified with a -D on the java call will override what is found in the properties file, so 'java -Duser.name=ted ...' will take precedence.  With ignoreResourceNotFound, the properties files can also be optionally absent without throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving it by not using context params. Instead we have defined

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            <value>file:C:\Users\Bill\prod-application.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

This way tries to load both files. On test servers we do not have the prod file so it is not loaded. On prod server the prod-application.properties file exists and overrides the test which is in the classpath. Cumbersome but works!

Comment: Although this works, it would have been nice if spring had a better solution. I am sure there are many people deploying apps to tomcat and want to externalize the props

Answer (score 2):

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${catalina.home}/conf/myFirst.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
<context:property-placeholder   location="classpath:second.properties"  ignore-unresolvable="true"  />
```

I do it like above. The `catalina.home` variable allows the properties file to be lcoated in the tomcat home conf directory.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, try to avoid specify locations. I think best thing for you is to use JNDI to achieve this.

In tomcat/conf/server.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/prod" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="${database.driverClassName}"
          url="${database.url}"
          username="${database.username}" password="${database.password}"
          maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
          maxWait="-1"/>
```

and In tomcat catalina.properties (If using Oracle XE otherwise change it accordingly):

```
database.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
database.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE
database.username=user
database.password=password
```

In your application create properties file in your classpath named jdbc.properties and put followings (If using Oracle XE otherwise change it accordingly)

```
jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@//localhost:1521/XE
```

then In Spring applicationContext.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/prod" />
    <property name="defaultObject" ref="dataSourceFallback" />
</bean>
```

```
<bean id="dataSourceFallback" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxActive">
        <value>4</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxIdle">
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>C:/Users/Bill/test-application.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Remove below code from `web.xml`

```
<Context>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>properties_location</param-name>
        <param-value>file:C:\Users\Bill\test-application.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
</Context>
```

Comment: My whole point is to have the location of the properties file OUTSIDE the war file so it cannot be put into the bean definition. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Tcserver and  server.xml to configure Resources like database,queues etc you can using the com.springsource.tcserver.properties.SystemProperties

Delcare this listener in server.xml like below

```
 <Listener className="com.springsource.tcserver.properties.SystemProperties"
            file.1="${catalina.base}/conf/password.properties"
            file.2="${catalina.base}/conf/server.properties"
            immutable="false"
            trigger="now"/>
```

Now you can externalize the properties to the two files password.properties and server.properties.